# Upload from any location not working with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, dirname

I am using PHPExcel plugin for reading excel and storing values in database.Its really cool and works very fine.But I have an issue when I am uploading an excel sheet from different location on my machine.
I guess it is bcoz,the **PHPExcel.php** has a constant defined

```
if (!defined('PHPEXCEL_ROOT')) {
   define('PHPEXCEL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
   require(PHPEXCEL_ROOT .'PHPExcel/Autoloader.php');
}
```

I would like to know how can I upload and read file from any location?Also,I am not saving my file after uploading,but just reading and saving records to DB, as the purpose is to just enter the records into a database.How can I fix it? The **documentation** is really good and extensive but I am a bit short of time to explore it and also a newbie to Obj Oriented PHP
Thanks for your time.

**PS** : I am not storing the file on the server,just reading and fetching the data from it.

Comment: I'm unsure of your actual problem here: is PHPExcel itself failing to load correctly as your reference to 'PHPEXCEL_ROOT' seems to suggest: or is it because it can't load your Excel files? If the latter, what errors are you getting? Are you giving the correct location for the file? Does the file have permissions allowing PHP to access it?

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for the attention.I get an error saying **Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not open diamond_new.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.** But if I upload a file from my root directory(i.e) the directory where **PHPExcel.php** and **PHPExcel** folder with classes are located,it works correctly.File has permissions as i can upload them from my base directory.But if I try to upload a file from some other drive(on local machine),it gives me the above error

Comment: When you specify the file for the load, make sure that you're passing the correct path and filename... if you're using a relative path, it should be relative to your scripts current working directory (getcwd) or use a full filesystem path

Comment: If I get you right,you mean that the phpreader doesn't get the file on the system,apart from the root directory?And i dont have to make any changes in the PHPExcel library but on my server side.I am not sure why,bcoz i don't face this issue with the other uploads I do(eg:images).Sorry if I sound naive!I am one.

Comment: The file must exist on the server where you're running PHPExcel, or must be uploaded to that server before PHPExcel can read it. Once the file is on that server, then you need to tell PHPExcel whereabouts on that server it is in order to load it

Comment: ok,it means I will need to upload the file to a location on the server say"excel/somefile.xlsx" and then try reading it.The file should be physically present when PHPExcel tries to read it.Then after the reading is done,I will have to unlink the file from the server to reduce the overhead as I am not goin to use them again.Am I right??If not pls correct.

Comment: That's right.. upload, read, unlink

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you sir for the valuable guidance.Will get back if I need some more help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mark Baker
Your comments helped me a lot and I fixed the issue.I was trying actually to reduce the load by not uploading the file.Instead just reading it and saving it.But it is not possible as we have to have the file physically located on the serve at the time of operation.
I have changed my approach and now **upload the file,read it and then unlink the file from the server after the operations are over**.

Thank you for the help and I appreciate your efforts in answering folks over PHPExcel issues.It is indeed a great tool to work on and looking forward to explore it more.